# Pyspark's write stringtype argument doesn't deal with null values

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, uuid

I am trying to write a dataset's data into postgres db using jdbc driver.

```
my_df.write().format('jdbc').mode('append')\
    .option('driver', 'org.postgresql.Driver')\
    .option('url', 'my_url')\
    .option('dbtable', 'my_dbtable')\
    .option('user', 'my_user').save()
```

Apparently pyspark tries to insert all textual types (i.e. uuid) as text by default and throws that error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid  but expression is of type character varying
```

Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

In order to overcome that issue I had to set a property:

```
'stringtype':"unspecified"
```

But that solution does not work on NULL values and throws that error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid  but expression is of type character
```

Which basically means that it tries to insert the NULL value as character. Separating the dataset to 2 datasets (as @Karuhanga suggested here [Pyspark nullable uuid type uuid but expression is of type character varying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671739/pyspark-nullable-uuid-type-uuid-but-expression-is-of-type-character-varying)) is not possible in my case. Did anyone face that issue and found a solution that does not fix a specific column?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a Null value in **uuid** columns, use as uuid by default like this:

```
uuid='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Comment: This is actually what I did (then i converted them to NULL when the process ended). Also used '01010000000000' for geometry but I think we should come up with a better solution. It's just a workaround.

Comment: @lidorbt did you find a better solution since then?

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find any solution for that - I just used @juanjosegdoj 's suggestion and changed all these values to null when the process ended